# openquery apears to be rolled back when done

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, openquery

I'm using the following query.

```
select * from OPENQUERY(EXITWEB,N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
                       declare @result table (id int);
                           insert into [system_files] ([is_public], [file_name], [file_size], [content_type], [disk_name], [updated_at], [created_at])
                    output inserted.id into @result(id)
                    values (N''1'',N''7349.jpg'',N''146921'',N''image/jpeg'',N''5799dcc8a1eb1413195192.jpg'',N''2016-07-28 10:22:00.000'',N''2016-07-28 10:22:00.000'')

                       declare @id int = (select top 1 id from @result)
                       select * from system_files where id = @id
                       insert into linkToExternal (id, id_ext) values(@id, 47)
                       --select @id
                       ')
```

when I perform a select from within the query it works just fine:

[image]

But when I go to check my database when the call has finished, the record is no longer there.

So I'm suspecting a transaction is rolled back. My question is: why. What can I do to prevent the transaction to be rolled back if that's the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as always, after days of struggling and me post a question on stackoverflow I find the solution: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1128997-391-1.aspx#bm1288825

> I was having the same problem as you and almost gave up on it but have
>   finally found an answer to the problem. Reading an article about
>   sharing data between stored procedures I discovered that OPENQUERY
>   issues an Implicit Transaction and that it was Rolling back my insert.
>   So I had to add an explicit Commit to my stored procedures, in
>   additional I discovered that if I use it in a query that has a Union
>   it has to be Commited twice. Since I'm doing my insert inside a BEGIN
>   TRY I can always just commit twice and not worry about whether it is
>   being used in a UNION. I'm returning different values if there is an
>   error but that was just apart of my debugging.

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM mm
JOIN OPENQUERY([LOCALSERVER], 'EXEC cms60.dbo.sp_RecordReportLastRun ''LPS'', ''Test''') RptStats ON 1=1


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RecordReportLastRun] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@LibraryName varchar(50),
@ReportName varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here
BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO cms60.dbo.ReportStatistics (LibraryName, ReportName, RunDate) VALUES (@LibraryName, @ReportName, GETDATE())
--
COMMIT; --Needed because OPENQUERY starts an Implicit Transaction but doesn't commit it.    
COMMIT; --Need second Commit when used in a UNION and although it throws an error when not used in a UNION doesn't cause a problem.
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT 2 Test
END CATCH
SELECT 1 Test 
END
```

In my case, adding a `;COMMIT;` after the inserts solved it, and made sure it got written into the database.